# SendKey alternative for simulating keyboard presses over a Citrix VDI

Tags: powershell, keyboard-events, sendkeys, enter, citrix

I am currently trying to simulate the <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and <kbd>Windows</kbd> keys being pressed over a Citrix VDI.

All the alphanumeric keys seem to work, but not the ones mentioned above.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

has been used

with the `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")` and the `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('~')` both been attempted for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

I have also attempted

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$wshell.AppActivate('R3 Store XenDesktop - Desktop Viewer')
Sleep 3
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
```

but it doesn't work, neither do <kbd>Tab</kbd> or the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key.

I do want to note, if it wasn't obvious, that the same commands work locally.

So what I am looking for now is how to send the 3 keys, since obviously the keys are sent over keyboard and they work, but not the command that `SendKeys` uses.

Funny thing is that the on-screen keyboard can also send the keys, so maybe if I can figure out how that encodes/sends the keys then I can do this

Comment: Are you executing these commands locally or on the remote?

Comment: The commands are being executed locally on my machine while the windows/app of the remote session is activated and fullscreen

Comment: Try executing them on the remote.  It's likely that Citrix is just filtering out your simulated keypresses (for legitimate security reasons).

Comment: unfortuntely I cant do that, the VDI is actually just a relaunched/regenerated template vm (of which my MSP org has no permissions beyond read), and my monitoring script needs to open a new instance everytime to monitor the whole process

Comment: Yep, I kinda knew that already.  You'll have to find another way.  If you don't have authority to work on the remote, well ...

Comment: You should read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Haha Thnx, I know I fall into that quite often. I'm running into a wall though, since THIS "solution" was my last grab to come up with a script that monitors  a UX scenario, of logging in and then launching an app and then logging off.. where simulating clicking wasnt working either due to display scale messes

Comment: I'm struggling to find a good reason why you need to do this.  If this is your VDI, there's almost certainly a better way to accomplish whatever you want to accomplish without using SendKeys over a Citrix connection.  If it's not your VDI ...

Comment: Partly, due to orders  from Client, well it doesnt have to be sending keys, I failed at the getting the mouse to the right location due to the messy display resolution bit. I just thought this would be a good replacement of that. Well truthfully, I dont know and cant figure out what other options I have to run a restricted VM where the VDI gets launched anyway

Comment: It would be much, much better if you and your client could find a way to solve this problem that isn't such a [Rube Goldberg contraption](https://img2.cgtrader.com/items/869850/1d3c9dfed4/large/mouse-trap-game-3d-model-obj-fbx-ma-mb-mtl-mel.jpg).

Comment: Alternatively, you can tell your client that you are unable to complete their request based on the current constraints of the access. Saying "No" is ok, the client is not always right.